# Setting Startup Web Role When Debugging Azure in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

This seems like a simple question, but I have googled it and cannot find an answer.

When I hit F5 in a Windows Azure solution in Visual Studio 2010 (the Azure project is the startup project), after a long time (a seperate issue) one of my web roles is running as expected.

However, I have 2 web roles in my solution, and I cant work out how to set a particular role as my 'default' role when running the solution in the debugger (as described above).

At the moment Im making a note of the tcp port assigned to each role in config, then changing the url in my browser for the web role I want.

Surely I should be able to set the default debugger web role in some property window somewhere - or am I missing something ??

Thanks

Dean

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2010/07/22/how-to-set-a-default-page-to-a-windows-azure-web-role-app-silverlight-asp-net-etc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the webrole(s) you do not want to start and click "properties" > "configuration" and uncheck "startup action" > "launch browser for" "HTTP Enpoint" [and "HTTPS Endpoint" if applicable] - leaving this/these options checked for the webrole you do want to start [development scenario].